# Beautifulsoup easy way to find tags directly beneath other tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In beautiful soup I know that you can find tags beneath other tags easily using CSS selectors i.e. if i have the following dummy xml:

```
<a>

  <b>
    <c>textabc1</c>
  </b>

  <b>
    <c>textabc2</c>
  </b>

  <c>
    <c>textacc</c>
  </c>

</a>
```

after I create the soup, suppose I'd like to find all tags c beneath b beneath a (a->b->c)
I'd simply run the following command:

```
soup.select('a > b > c')
```

which gets me:

```
[<c>textabc1</c>, <c>textabc2</c>]
```

is there any easy way to do this not using CSS selectors?

I spend the afternoon trying to find an easy way to do so with the "more standard" beautiful soup methods. In the example I provided there are 3 levels of tag indentation but is very important to mention that I won't be able to know the xml nor the tags and their indentation level until runtime (everything will be passed as parameters to the script), so I may need to find tags from 1 to n indentation levels (if I knew in advance that i'd have to search 3 indentation levels at most I could've probably used 3 indented loops and a combination of findAll/findChildren methods. I thought of some recursive method but the logic seems complicated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't know how many level downs a target tag is, how do you select them? By text content? Also, if for some reason you don't want to use css selectors, can you use other libraries (like lxml)?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is all occurances of the  tag. then try the following.

```
all_c_elements = soup.find_all("c")
```

This will return all  elements on the page, regardless of how far down the tree structure they are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's anything you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html='''
<a>
  <b>
    <c>textabc1</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>textabc2</c>
  </b>
  <c>
    <c>textacc</c>
  </c>
</a>
'''
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(html)
cs = doc.selects('a>a|b').c
print (cs)
cs = doc.a.getElements(['a','b']).getElement('c')
print (cs)
cs = doc.selects('a>a|b|c').c
print (cs)
```

Result:

```
[{'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textabc1'}, {'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textabc2'}]
[{'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textabc1'}, {'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textabc2'}]
[{'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textabc1'}, {'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textabc2'}, {'tag': 'c', 'html': 'textacc'}]
```